# Cells in tabu move vertically when \color begins the cell

Tags: color, tabu

When I use `\color` in the beginning of a cell in tabu, the contents of the cell are shifted downwards:

[image: screenshot of MWE]

The issue does not occur when there is any character in front of the `\color`, but a `\null` does not help (in fact, it increases the shift).

Here is the code for the example above:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{tabu}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabu} to 4cm {XX}
    Lorem & Ipsum \\
    Dolor & {\color{red}Sit} Amet
\end{tabu}

\end{document}
```

Why is the text shifted down, and what is the correct way to color the first word of a cell?

Comment: Use `\textcolor{red}{Sit}`, or `\leavevmode` before the color.

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Why don't writing the answer directly?

Comment: Great, this works! It's a bit sad that this also affects `\alert` in beamer, though. 
Would you mind converting this to an answer?

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/55187/align-cell-height-of-the-tabularx-rows/55193#55193  or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2286/fancyheader-mis-placement/2304#2304

Comment: also footnote on page 6 of  color package documentation: `texdoc grfguide`